# Using Metabase with Firebase Realtime Database for data analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, metabase

Is it possible to setup and use **Metabase** (https://metabase.com/) to directly (or indirectly, maybe via Google BigQuery) connect to **Firebase** realtime Database to fetch data to analyze? Any advice or tutorial links (if available) will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Firebase support is still an open issue on Metabase: https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/4213

Noteworthy [comment](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/4213#issuecomment-286479061)/opinion from contributor/CEO of Metabase:

> For what it's worth, for firebase specifically, we'd strongly suggest getting your database and/or analytics events into BigQuery somehow vs coding against the database rest api directly.
>
> I'm leaving this issue open in case to not squash anyone's motivation, but even if it does get addressed in a PR, I'd still recommend using BQ =)